# .net XmlSerializer on overridden properties

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, xml-serialization, overriding

I have a base class with an abstract property:

```
public abstract int ID {get;set;}
```

now, I have a subclass, which is XmlSerialized. So, it has:

```
[XmlElement("something")]
public override int ID {
get { //... }
set { //... }
}
```

I cannot move the XmlElement attribute to baseclass, since every subclass will have a different xml elementname.

Now, when I deserialize this class I get the following error:

> Member 'Subclass.ID' hides inherited
>   member 'BaseClass.ID', but has
>   different custom attributes.

What can I do?

Comment: Consider using 'new' keyword in the property declaration, which may solve your problem.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Serialization and deserialization of derived types works when the overridden properties have `[XmlElement]` and `[XmlAttribute]` attributes, by adding an `[XmlIgnore]` attribute.

The base class can be made abstract so that it can never be instantiated and therefore serialized or deserialized.

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Base
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public abstract Int32 ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the base class property protected and non-abstract, then give each derived class an appropriately named property implemented in terms of the base class property:

```
// Base class
protected int InternalID {get; set;}

// Derived class
[XmlElement]
public int SomethingID
{
  get {return InternalID;}
  set {InternalID = value;}
}
```

Comment: But the base class needs to implement an interface... That's the whole reason why it has an ID property.